# Re-enabling windows 7 search

Tags: windows-7, windows-search, services

So I disabled the search service by accident, the basic shell integrated one which can be accessed from <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>.

How can I re-enable this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Under **Control Panel** click on **Programs**:

  [image]
- Under **Programs and Features** click on **Turn Windows Features On or Off**:

  [image]
- In the dialog, check the **Windows Search** checkbox and hit OK:

  [image]

You will be prompted to restart. If you've saved all your work you can now restart.

Comment: Heh, I try! Let me know if it works :)