# Enable Windows Search again in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, windows-search

I have the same problem as this one:

[Re-enabling windows 7 search](https://superuser.com/questions/95161/re-enabling-windows-7-search)

Except it's Windows 8 and there is no option for "Windows Search" in the list of features. I disabled it when I installed my computer, and now there is no way to enable it again.

Comment: I believe the OP disabled Windows Search at some time in the past and the question is buried in the title, "How do I re-enable Windows Search in Windows-8".

Answer (score 0):

I believe you just need to do the opposite of what is described [here](http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/how-to-permanently-disable-search-indexing-in-windows-8/).

In short;

- Open up `services.msc`
- Look for the service named "Windows Search"
- Right click and select properties
- Change the startup type to "Automatic (delayed start)"
- Click apply and reboot

This should fix your problem!

Comment: No, you see, I can't do that, because the service doesn't exist since I disabled it.

Thanks for trying, though. I really have tried everything I can find, but everything with search is gone, in services, settings, you name it.

Comment: So you didn't disable it you deleted it? Do you know what you did to get rid of it?

Comment: Yes, I went to "Programs and Features" in Control Panel and selected "Turn Windows features on or off" and unchecked "Windows Search". Now that option isn't available anymore.